# sql query misses out two columns within the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Ok Hi I have a slightly weird problem that I cannot figure out mysql query posts the uniq_id in the title column instead of its own and the title, blurb and uniq_id end up empty.

to start off with i create a uniq_id in php and then assign this to be a value within a hidden field within a form this is the code:

```
  $uid = uniqid();
  /*echo $uid;*/

  echo " <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"$uid\" name=\"Uniq_id\"/>";
```

this is then posted using the form submit button,

then on the next page $_POST catches all of the values and turns them into variables this is the code for that:

```
$Title = $_POST['Title'];
$Blurb = $_POST['Blurb'];
$Subject = $_POST['cat'];
$Section = $_POST['typ'];
$Principle = $_POST['princ'];
$Verify = $_POST['verification'];
$Career = $_POST['career'];
$Job = $_POST['job'];
$Uniq_id = $_POST['Uniq_id'];
```

the variables are then used within this page within the sql query bellow which is ment to post these values into the database the function below is the one that is run when you click the submit button

```
    public function addNewRecord($Subject, $Section, $Principle, $Job, $Career, $Title, $Blurb, $Uniq_id)
            { 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `careersintheclassroom`.`media` (`media_id`, `subject_id`, `section_id`, `principle_id`, `title`, `blurb`, `verified`, `media_uniqid`) 
                       VALUES (NULL, '".$Subject."', '".$Section."', '".$Principle."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')"; // sql query 

                 return mysql_query($sql, $this->conn); // connection to database and also getting the results from query

  }
```

when it posts the values to the page with this function it prints the values on a page showing me all the values this is one of them.

```
INSERT INTO `careersintheclassroom`.`media` (`media_id`, `subject_id`, `section_id`, `principle_id`, `jobrole_id`, `career_id`, `title`, `blurb`, `verified`, `media_uniqid`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', 'Title1', 'Blurb1', '0', '532061df6b80d');File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.
```

Now in the database it does something strange it posts in the first 4 values correctly then it inserts the Uniq_id into the title doesn't insert anything into blurb then put the correct value into verified and then leave the last column blank to,

Comment: I would verify that the variables you are passing to the query are correct.  The query itself looks well-formed.  (Also, you should read up on prepared statements using `mysqli` or `pdo` http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php - the mysql extensions are going to be deprecated by PHP soon-ish.)

Comment: did you check the content of your params after calling your function addNewRecord?

Comment: @sqlab what do you mean check the content as in do i check what is in the variables before they are inserted ?

Comment: - Maybe You passed Wrong Data in 'addNewRecord()' so first check it

Comment: maybe you use the wrong order of your params when calling the function addNewRecord

Comment: @sqlab if you look at my original question I printed out the sql query when it gets the details and they all look correct when i look at them

Comment: What happens if you insert these values manually e.g. with phpMyAdmin or in the mysql shell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of the verified field?

Try this, notice the quotes around `0`:

```
VALUES (NULL, '".$Subject."', '".$Section."', '".$Principle."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '"0"', '".$Uniq_id."')"; // sql query
```

Comment: i have tried but it greys out all of my which usually means it is incorrect

Comment: the 0 gets inserted correctly into the database it is the title and blurb that dont and then the $Uniq_id is posted in the wrong column

Comment: @user3387522 what column does `$Uniq_id` get posted to? and title and blurb are missing?

Comment: @user3387522 Also, have you tried just going to mysql and running your sql statement as you show in your edit?

Comment: this was the correct way to display the values within the sql query

Answer (score 1):

Hi Guys thanks for all of the answers I have figured out what the problem is I have figured out that my syntax for the mysql query was wrong I used phpmyadmin to create the php code and then altered it to fit the functions but this was wrong the code i was using was:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `careersintheclassroom`.`media` (`media_id`, `subject_id`, `section_id`, `principle_id`, `title`, `blurb`, `verified`, `media_uniqid`) 
 VALUES (NULL, '".$SUBJECT."', '".$SECTION."', '".$Principle."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')";
```

instead the correct code that it should be is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO media (media_id, subject_id, section_id, principle_id, title, blurb, verified, media_uniqid)
VALUES ('NULL', '".$Subject."', '".$Section."', '".$Principle."', '".$Title."', '".$Blurb."', '0', '".$Uniq_id."')";
```

As you can see the columns have got `` around them this is wrong so removing them inserts the details correctly into the columns

Thanks for everything guys you have helped a lot.

Comment: I was using phpmyadmins code but in the end that was wrong so I looked in a book sams teach yourself sql in 10 minutes and it worked like a treat @paqogomez

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the "title" column is configured to insert a guid for every row insert. Check the column definition for title. Also did you verify that the Blurb and media_uniqueid columns values passed on to the function to be inserted are not null/blank for some reason.. Just checking..

Comment: I haven't created anything differently because I create the table about 3 weeks ago and then only added in the uniq_id in yesterday due to only realizing I need to use a uniq_id